# how to accept only a future date in a form odoo

Tags: odoo

here is the code that i tried:

```
@api.onchange('date_pub')
def get_right_date(self):
    if self.date_pub:
        if datetime.strptime(self.date_pub, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT).date() < datetime.now().date():
            raise Warning(_( "impossible d'insérer une date passée"))
            self.date_pub=datetime.now().date()
```

I am getting the error message ("impossible d'insérer une date passée"), but the field date_pub is not updated, the same date picked up by the user is inserted in database!

Help!!

Comment: no, after the warning I want to insert the current date or to clear the inserted value and ask the user to re insert a valide date, you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For restricting the **insertion of wrong  value in side the databse** you should use **@api.constrains**
Like:

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('date_pub')
def _check_date_pubd(self):
    if self.date_pub:
        if datetime.strptime(self.date_pub, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT).date() < datetime.now().date():
            raise ValidationError(_('impossible d'insérer une date passée.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code IS help to allow only future and current(today)'s date

@api.onchange('start_dt')

```
def check_date(self):

    selected_date = datetime.strptime(self.start_dt, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    today = datetime.now().date()
    todaydate = datetime.strptime(str(today), "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    if selected_date < todaydate:
        raise Warning("CURRENT OR FUTURE DATE IS ONLY ACCEPTABLE")
```